# PHP create video thumbnail from remote url

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

I've my video storage on `google cloud`, I need to create the `thumbnail` for my videos it's gonna be remote, I tried to use `FFmpeg` to create and getting the content of the thumbs, but it's not working, it just returns null for me.

```
public function create_video_thumb($video){

        $ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';

        try{

            $cmd = "ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -f image2 'test.jpg' ";

            $return = array(
                'success'=>true,
                'content' => $cmd
            );

        }catch (Exception $e){
            $return = $e->getMessage();
        }


        return   $return;
    }
```

Return:

```
{
      "sucess":true,
      "content":null
}
```

Comment: That's the point of `$ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';` if it's not used

Comment: Are you running this on your own server or web hosting? Also i don't see you executing anything. Use `exec($cmd);` or `passthru($cmd);` if you want the raw return content of the command (if provided)

Comment: @Yolo Thanks, passthru was exactly what I needed